# PHP Date comparison issue

Tags: php

I am trying to see if a date is between the first and last of the current month. I have tried to convert the following $dateInfo string to a date, so I can compare the values... How can I accomplish this?
DateInfo has to be in the format below.

Variables:

```
$dateInfo = '20150624T14:49:59'
$dFirst = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$dLast = new DateTime('last day of this month');
```

The comparison:

```
if(($dateInfo >= $dFirst) && (  $dateInfo<= $dLast )){
    echo 'something';}
}
```

Comment: google: `strtotime()`

Comment: So you have tried: `if((strtotime($dateInfo) >= $dFirst->getTimestamp()) && (  strtotime($dateInfo) <= $dLast->getTimestamp())){ echo "something";}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using DateTime object:

```
<?php
$dateInfo = new DateTime('20150724T14:49:59');
$dFirst = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$dLast = new DateTime('last day of this month');

if (($dateInfo >= $dFirst) && ($dateInfo <= $dLast)) {
    $string = "%s is between %s and %s";
    printf($string, $dateInfo->format('d/M/Y'), $dFirst->format('d/M/Y'), $dLast->format('d/M/Y'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dateInfo = strtotime('20150624T14:49:59');
$dFirst = strtotime(date('01-m-Y')); // first day of month
$dLast = strtotime(date('Y-m-t'));  // last day of month

if(($dateInfo >= $dFirst) && (  $dateInfo<= $dLast )){
    echo 'something';}
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateInfo = new DateTime('20150624T14:49:59');
```

This worked form me

Answer (score 0):

You can compare timestamps with [DateTime::getTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php).

```
$dateInfo = '20150724T14:49:59';

$myDate = new DateTime($dateInfo);

$dFirst = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$dLast = new DateTime('last day of this month');

$occursThisMonth = $dFirst->getTimestamp() <= $myDate->getTimestamp() && 
                   $myDate->getTimestamp() <= $dLast->getTimestamp();
```